# For small $|x|<1$, $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, is it true that $e^{\alpha t}-(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2 x^2)^{\frac{t}{x}}=O(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

So expanding out the second term gives:
$$(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2 x^2)^{\frac{t}{x}}=e^{\frac{t}{x}\ln(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2 x^2)}$$

$$=e^{\frac{t}{x}((\alpha x+\alpha^2 x^2)-\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^2 x^2+2\alpha^3 x^3+\alpha^4 x^4)+\frac{1}{3}(\alpha^3 x^3+3\alpha^4 x^4+3\alpha^5 x^5+\alpha^6 x^6)+...)}$$

$$=e^{t((\alpha +\alpha^2 x)-\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^2 x+2\alpha^3 x^2+\alpha^4 x^3)+\frac{1}{3}(\alpha^3 x^2+3\alpha^4 x^3+3\alpha^5 x^4+\alpha^6 x^5)+...)}$$

$$=e^{t(\alpha +\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 x -\frac{2}{3}\alpha^3x^2+\frac{1}{4}\alpha^4 x^3+...)}$$

So $$e^{\alpha t}-e^{t(\alpha +\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 x -\frac{2}{3}\alpha^3x^2+\frac{1}{4}\alpha^4 x^3+...)}$$

$$=e^{\alpha t}-e^{\alpha t}e^{t(\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 x -\frac{2}{3}\alpha^3x^2+\frac{1}{4}\alpha^4 x^3+...)}$$

$$=e^{\alpha t}-e^{\alpha t}(1+t(\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 x -\frac{2}{3}\alpha^3x^2+\frac{1}{4}\alpha^4 x^3+...)+...$$

$$=-e^{\alpha t}t(\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 x -\frac{2}{3}\alpha^3x^2+\frac{1}{4}\alpha^4 x^3+...)+...$$

And so this appears to be $O(x)$? I feel like I've gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: Your calculations are correct. There are not mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your work is perfectly correct but, if I may suggest, it could be done faster.

Considering $$\Delta=e^{\alpha t}-(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2 x^2)^{\frac{t}{x}}$$ let $\alpha t= T$ and $\alpha x= X$ to make
$$\Delta=e^{T}-(1+X+X^2)^{\frac{T}{X}}$$
$$y=(1+X+X^2)^{\frac{T}{X}}\implies \log(y)=\frac T X \log(1+X+X^2)$$ By Taylor
$$\log(1+X+X^2)=X+\frac{X^2}{2}+O\left(X^3\right)$$
$$\log(y)=T+\frac{T X}{2}+O\left(X^2\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e^T \left(1+\frac{1}{2}TX+O\left(X^2\right)\right)$$
$$\Delta=\frac{1}{2}TXe^T+O\left(X^2\right)=O\left(X\right)$$

Comment: Actually, $$\Delta=-\frac{1}{2}TXe^T+O\left(X^2\right)=O\left(X\right)$$ Have you done it faster? The original poster wrote $12$ lines and you too.

Comment: @Angelo. Then count also the numbers of characters.

Comment: Claude, first fix your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove that for small $x$ ( that is $|x|<1$) and for any $\alpha,t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ it is true that $\;\color{brown}{e^{\alpha t}-\left(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2 x^2\right)^{\frac{t}{x}}=O(x)}\;,$

we will calculate the following limit:

$\color{brown}{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{\alpha t}-\left(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2x^2\right)^{\frac tx}}x}\;.$

First of all we will prove that , for any $\;a,b\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

$\color{green}{\lim\limits_{u\to0}\,\dfrac1u\left[\left(\dfrac{1+u+au^2}{e^u}\right)^{\frac bu}-1\right]=b\left(a-\dfrac12\right)}\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

If $\;b=0\;,\;$ $(*)$ is trivially true.

If $\;b\ne0\;,\;$ it results that

$\lim\limits_{u\to0}\,\dfrac1u\left[\left(\dfrac{1+u+au^2}{e^u}\right)^{\frac bu}-1\right]=$

$=\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{e^{-b}\left(1+u+au^2\right)^{\frac bu}-1}u=$

$=\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{e^{-b}\cdot e^{\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)}-1}u=$

$=\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{e^{\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b}-1}u=$

$=\lim\limits_{u\to0}\left[\dfrac{e^{\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b}-1}{\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b}\cdot\dfrac{\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b}u\right]=$

$=b\cdot\lim\limits_{u\to0}\left[\dfrac{e^{\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b}-1}{\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b}\cdot\dfrac{\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-u}{u^2}\right]\color{blue}{(1)}$

Since $\;\lim\limits_{z\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+z)-z}{z^2}=-\dfrac12\;,\;$ it follows that

$\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-u}{u^2}=$

$=\lim\limits_{u\to0}\left[\dfrac{\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-\left(u+au^2\right)}{u^2}+a\right]=$

$=\lim\limits_{u\to0}\left[\dfrac{\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-\left(u+au^2\right)}{\left(u+au^2\right)^2}\cdot\left(1+au\right)^2+a\right]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{by letting } z=u+au^2}}{=}\lim\limits_{z\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+z\right)-z}{z^2}\cdot\lim\limits_{u\to0}\left(1+au\right)^2+a=$

$=-\dfrac12\cdot1+a=a-\dfrac12\;,\quad$ hence ,

$\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-u}{u^2}=a-\dfrac12\;.\quad\color{blue}{(2)}$

Moreover,

$\lim\limits_{u\to0}\left[\dfrac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b\right]=$

$=b\cdot\lim\limits_{u\to0}\left[\dfrac{\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-u}{u^2}\cdot u\right]=$

$=b\left(a-\dfrac12\right)\cdot0=0\;,\quad$ hence ,

$\lim\limits_{u\to0}\left[\dfrac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b\right]=0\;.\quad\color{blue}{(3)}$

From $\;(1),\;(2),\;(3)\;,\;$ we get that

$\lim\limits_{u\to0}\,\dfrac1u\left[\left(\dfrac{1+u+au^2}{e^u}\right)^{\frac bu}-1\right]=$

$=b\cdot\lim\limits_{u\to0}\left[\dfrac{e^{\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b}-1}{\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b}\cdot\dfrac{\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-u}{u^2}\right]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\quad\text{by letting }\\z=\frac bu\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-b}}{=}b\cdot\lim\limits_{z\to0}\dfrac{e^z-1}z\cdot\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+u+au^2\right)-u}{u^2}=$

$=b\cdot1\cdot\left(a-\dfrac12\right)=b\left(a-\dfrac12\right)\;.$

So we have proved $\;(*)\;.$

Now we will prove that , for any $\;a,b\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

$\color{green}{\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{e^b-\left(1+u+au^2\right)^{\frac bu}}u=be^b\left(\dfrac12-a\right)}\;.\quad\color{blue}{(**)}$

$\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{e^b-\left(1+u+au^2\right)^{\frac bu}}u=$

$=-e^b\cdot\lim\limits_{u\to0}\,\dfrac1u\left[\dfrac{\left(1+u+au^2\right)^{\frac bu}}{e^b}-1\right]=$

$=-e^b\cdot\lim\limits_{u\to0}\,\dfrac1u\left[\left(\dfrac{1+u+au^2}{e^u}\right)^{\frac bu}-1\right]\underset{\overbrace{\text{by using }(*)}}{=}$

$=-e^b\cdot b\left(a-\dfrac12\right)= be^b\left(\dfrac12-a\right)\;.$

So we have just proved $\;(**)\;.$

Finally we will calculate the following limit:

$\color{brown}{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{\alpha t}-\left(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2x^2\right)^{\frac tx}}x}\;.$

Since $\;\alpha\ne0\;$ and $\;t\ne0\;,\;$ it results that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{\alpha t}-\left(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2x^2\right)^{\frac tx}}x=$

$=\alpha\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{\alpha t}-\left(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2x^2\right)^{\frac{\alpha t}{\alpha x}}}{\alpha x}\underset{\overbrace{\text{by letting }u=\alpha x}}{=}$

$=\alpha\cdot\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{e^{\alpha t}-\left(1+u+u^2\right)^{\frac{\alpha t}u}}u\underset{\overbrace{\text{by using }(**)\text{ with}\\a=1\text{ and } b=\alpha t}}{=}$

$=\alpha\cdot\alpha t\,e^{\alpha t}\left(\dfrac12-1\right)=-\dfrac12\alpha^2te^{\alpha t}\ne0\;,\quad$ hence ,

$\color{brown}{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{\alpha t}-\left(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2x^2\right)^{\frac tx}}x=-\dfrac12\alpha^2te^{\alpha t}\ne0}\;$

for any $\;\alpha,t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\;.$

It proves that for small $x$ ( that is $|x|<1$) and for any $\alpha,t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ it is true that $\;\color{brown}{e^{\alpha t}-\left(1+\alpha x+\alpha^2 x^2\right)^{\frac{t}{x}}=O(x)}\;.$